# Post item into database without filling the foreign key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, post, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web API model for banking system each branch have a `managerId` which is a foreign key to the `users` table.

When I want to post a new branch, I have to fill all the columns for branch and the manager. How can I only insert branch columns?

`Branches` entity:

```
public class Branch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public User BranchManager { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

`Users` entity:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int ? SuperviseID { get; set; }
    public UserTypes UserType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SuperviseID")]
    public User? Supervise { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Branch>? Branches { get; set; }
}
```

My code:

```
public void PostBranch(Branch branch)
{
   var db = new OrganizationDbContext();
   db.Add(branch);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Post request body:

```
{
  "id": 5,
  "branchName": "Bank",
  "phoneNumber": "9999999",
  "branchManagerId": 7
}
```

When I left other columns empty, I get an error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column

Comment: You just need to make the `BranchManager` in your `Branch` class nullable: `public User? BranchManager { get; set; }`

Comment: I can't see BbanchManagerId property in Branch class, you will have to add it

Comment: Thanks for your answer this would fix the null error but if I already have a Branch manager I can't use it, It gives duplicate error.
By the way thanks for editing my question. @marc_s

Answer (score 0):

I find where the problem is:

```
public void PostBranch(Branch branch)
{
   var db = new OrganizationDbContext();
   db.Add(branch);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

`db.Add(branch)` should convert to `db.Branches.Add(branch)`